# IOS simulator crashing

Tags: xcode

I just download Ios 13.7 simulator in Xcode 12.2, it is crashing without opening.

```
Failed to start launchd_sim: could not bind to session, launchd_sim may have crashed or quit responding
```

I am very new to this, please help. I search on internet also but could not found any solution. System restart / XCODE restart i have done.

Comment: Are you on Big Sur?

Comment: yes, just got new mac mini

Comment: So it's an M1? That's the problem. Earlier simulators do not work on M1. Only the iOS 14 simulators are working.

Comment: ya, new M1, anyway to work with earlier simulators.

Comment: Just wait and see if Apple gets them working. It's early days. :)

Comment: Updating to Big Sur **11.0.1** worked for me